# How do I make the "1.9.2" Ruby string point to the final release with RVM?

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I'm using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage my Ruby environment on OSX, and currently it's interpreting '1.9.2' as `ruby-1.9.2-rc2` instead of the final release. How can I update this to make it behave as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've updated rvm with the `rvm update` command. From there you can install 1.9.2 with `rvm install 1.9.2`. It'll install and compile ruby 1.9.2-p0. From there, it should interpret `1.9.2` as the final release. I'm also on a mac, and this worked for me after having rc2 installed.

Comment: Already had 1.9.2-p0 installed, in fact. That's what made this particularly annoying. `rvm update` worked, thanks!